# GET ALL LDAP USERS WITH LDAP BEAN

Tags: ldap, alfresco, activiti

I am currently devloping a java web application based on activiti and i want to use ldap as an authentification system.
I Configured ldap as it its 's shown,but when i write this command in java  System.out.println(processEngine.getIdentityService().createGroupQuery().list().size());  i got an  error "This query is not supported by the LDAPGroupManager".So what can i do ? 
Thank you in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
<property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000" />
<property name="username" value="sa" />
<property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
<property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
<property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />

<property name="configurators">
<list>
<bean class="org.activiti.ldap.LDAPConfigurator">

<!-- Server connection params -->
<property name="server" value="ldap://localhost" />
<property name="port" value="10389" />
<property name="user" value="uid=admin,ou=system" />
<property name="password" value="secret" />

<!-- Query params -->
<property name="baseDn" value="o=mojo" /> 
<property name="queryUserByUserId" value="(&amp;(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={0}))" />
<property name="queryUserByFullNameLike" value="(&amp;(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(|({0}=*{1}*)({2}=*{3}*)))" />
<property name="queryGroupsForUser" value="(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember={0}))" />

<!-- Attribute config -->
<property name="userIdAttribute" value="uid" />
<property name="userFirstNameAttribute" value="cn" />
<property name="userLastNameAttribute" value="sn" />

<property name="groupIdAttribute" value="cn" />
<property name="groupNameAttribute" value="cn" />

</bean>
</list>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
<property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
</bean>
<bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRepositoryService" />
<bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getRuntimeService" />
<bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getTaskService" />
<bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getHistoryService" />
<bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngine" factory-method="getManagementService" />

</beans>
```

Comment: we can't get all the ldap users with the bean this is  not supported by the LDAPGroupManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can't get all the ldap users with the bean this is not supported by the LDAPGroupManager